# Exe file with GUID as name from c:\windows\installer launched at boot

Tags: windows-8

When checking the items that start at boot (task manager => start-up) I noticed the first item was an exe called "C:\Windows\Installer{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe"

After rebooting the item remains in the folder and startup list
There are other similarly guid-named files there, but they are not listed in the startup items.
Launching the exe file manually shows an error that this file cannot be run with my pc.

Any idea what it might be, why it's (still) there, if I can remove it?

Comment: What does the properties->details tab of the file show?

Comment: Type:application; size 104 KB; Date Mod:2014/01/02 22:02. All else blank

Comment: search your registry for the GUID, you should find more info listed in the uninstall registry key.  (like the name of the app)   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or in HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Analysis

Looking for `{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}` on the net yields a [couple of diagnostic logs](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%7B01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18%7D%22) where the same [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) appears:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
"{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}" = ServeToMe

O4 - Startup: C:\Users\AdrianJ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ServeToMe.lnk = C:\Users\AdrianJ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}\_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe ()
```

The GUID is indeed related to [ServeToMe](http://zqueue.com/servetome/), a streaming media server application.

> StreamToMe is a media player application for Macs and iOS devices (iPad, iPhone and iPod Touch) that plays video, music and photo files (in a wide variety of formats) streamed over the network from another Mac or PC.
>
> Files are live-transcoded into the native format for your device so you don't need to pre-convert your media. Adaptive bitrates mean that you can stream over WiFi or 3G.

The program was installed on 2014/01/02 at 22:02 by selecting the **Everyone** option during setup (**Install for anyone who uses this computer**). Choosing **Just me** would install those .exe files in `C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}` instead.

### Additional information

The hexadecimal-named `.exe` file is <strike>a startup stub</strike> just an icon file with a different extension and won't run <strike>manually because apparently it's not meant so</strike> because it's *not* an executable file at all. Here's an excerpt of the file content:

```
00000000  00 00 01 00 05 00 0D 00 00 00 49 48 44 52 89 5C  ..........IHDR‰\
00000010  01 00 56 00 00 00 30 30 00 00 01 00 20 00 68 26  ..V...00.... .h&
00000020  00 00 DF 5C 01 00 20 20 00 00 01 00 20 00 28 11  ..ß\..  .... .(.
00000030  00 00 47 83 01 00 18 18 00 00 01 00 20 00 B8 09  ..Gƒ........ .¸.
00000040  00 00 6F 94 01 00 10 10 00 00 01 00 20 00 68 04  ..o”........ .h.
00000050  00 00 27 9E 01 00 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00  ..'ž..‰PNG......
00000060  00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 08 06  ..IHDR..........
00000070  00 00 00 5C 72 A8 66 00 00 04 24 69 43 43 50 49  ...\r¨f...$iCCPI
00000080  43 43 20 50 72 6F 66 69 6C 65 00 00 38 11 85 55  CC Profile..8.…U
00000090  DF 6F DB 54 14 3E 89 6F 52 A4 16 3F 20 58 47 87  ßoÛT.>‰oR¤.? XG‡
000000A0  8A C5 AF 55 53 5B B9 1B 1A AD C6 06 49 93 A5 ED  ŠÅ¯US[¹...Æ.I“¥í
```

The actual program is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zqueue\ServeToMe\ServeToMe.exe` on a 64-bit Windows.

These are the file properties and checksum/hashes for version **3.9.0.3053**, which is the latest available from the official website:

```
File: _2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe
File size: 104 KB (107151 bytes)
---
CRC-32: 6ce38c7c
MD4: ce2ab0e3e4fc50c5404c0cfb34d80a6a
MD5: 95173b90d8b163f18d9d2d5d5e15c580
SHA-1: 16e9801bb550b9dd9ea8de89e65de83d540e41da

File: ServeToMe.exe
File size: 177 KB (181760 bytes) 
---
CRC-32: 377c83d0
MD4: ecde064905360067b5fb7a8bca6ece40
MD5: 13d2c9bf99b300d9cf58e19c1ad752e4
SHA-1: 16658941876752798e9a39acd7792815d0b8e55c
```

### Shortcut inspection

When the program is installed for everyone, the shortcut full path is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ServeToMe.lnk`. If you check the properties you can see the target field is grayed out and cannot be changed. This is because it's a particular, so-called **advertised shortcut** created by Windows Installer:

> Windows Installer introduces a special type of shortcut which, while transparent to the user, contains additional metadata that Windows Installer uses through its shell integration to verify the state of the specified application's installation prior to launching the application.

We can confirm that by [parsing](http://code.google.com/p/lnk-parser/) the shortcut:

```
[Filename]: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ServeToMe.lnk

[Header]
Date created: Unknown
Last accessed: Unknown
Last modified: Unknown
File size: 0 bytes
File attributes: 0x00000000 (None)
Icon index: 0
ShowWindow value: 1 (SW_SHOWNORMAL / SW_NORMAL)
Hot key value: 0x0000 (None)
Link flags: 0x000050f9 (HasLinkTargetIDList, HasRelativePath, HasWorkingDir, HasArguments, HasIconLocation, IsUnicode, HasDarwinID, HasExpIcon)

[Link Target ID List]
CLSID: 20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d = My Computer

Drive: C:\

Last modified: 01/16/2014 (18:48:54.0) [UTC]
Folder attributes: 0x00000010 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
Short directory name: Windows
Date created: 07/14/2009 (03:20:10.0) [UTC]
Last accessed: 01/16/2014 (18:48:54.0) [UTC]
Long directory name: Windows

Last modified: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Folder attributes: 0x00000016 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
Short directory name: INSTAL~1
Date created: 12/15/2013 (18:45:12.0) [UTC]
Last accessed: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Long directory name: Installer

Last modified: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Folder attributes: 0x00000010 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
Short directory name: {01BD6~1
Date created: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Last accessed: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Long directory name: {01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}

File size: 107151 bytes
Last modified: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
File attributes: 0x00000021 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)
8.3 filename: _2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe
Date created: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Last accessed: 01/17/2014 (11:56:26.0) [UTC]
Long filename: _2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe

[String Data]
Relative path (UNICODE): ..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}\_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe
Working Directory (UNICODE): C:\Program Files (x86)\Zqueue\ServeToMe\
Arguments (UNICODE): startup
Icon location (UNICODE): C:\Windows\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}\_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe

[Darwin Properties]
Application identifier (ASCII): Q9UW!o_!_?09WJ'i$c!+>Ipj.(bOirX&j$Vp+8v_j
Application identifier (UNICODE): Q9UW!o_!_?09WJ'i$c!+>Ipj.(bOirX&j$Vp+8v_j

[Icon Location]
Icon location (ASCII): %SystemRoot%\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}\_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe
Icon location (UNICODE): %SystemRoot%\Installer\{01BD6AAA-0419-498A-BAE3-B50D078BEA18}\_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe
```

`_2A3423A49F6BC3B3E88E06.exe` only serves as icon location and `ServeToMe.exe` is not referenced *anywhere*; yet the shortcut works. How so? The `HasDarwinID` flag is enabled which means the shortcut contains a [DarwinDataBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871369.aspx):

> The DarwinDataBlock structure specifies an application identifier that can be used instead of a [link target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#link_target)[IDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#item_id_list) to install an application when a [shell link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7b5968-68f5-4e5c-8b11-00a6f4ae98ff#shell_link) is activated.

In this case the application identifier is `Q9UW!o_!_?09WJ'i$c!+>Ipj.(bOirX&j$Vp+8v_j`, which can be found in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\C:|Program Files (x86)|Zqueue|ServeToMe|ServeToMe.exe` registry key.

> This cryptic-looking string, sometimes referred to as a "Darwin Descriptor," is actually an encoded representation of a specific product, component, and feature. If this extra value exists, Windows Installer will decode the data, and use it to perform checks against that product and component. If the component is found to be missing or corrupt, Windows Installer will launch a repair to restore the missing file or data, and finally launch the referenced application as normal, passing the appropriate command-line options to it.

## Resolution

If you do use **ServeToMe**, you can disable the startup entry if you  want to avoid automatic launch. You would then need to run the program manually when required. If you don't need it, you can simply uninstall it.

## References

- [[MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx)
- [LNK - Forensics Wiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/LNK#External_Links)
- [Application Resiliency: Unlock the Hidden Features of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302344.aspx)
- [About Windows Installer Shortcuts](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/about-windows-installer-shortcuts)

Comment: That is a thorough answer, thanks. This is, however, the first time I see a program act like this although there are multiple programs that are installed for all users and do launch on start (think AVG, Launchy etc). Why does streamtome act differently then the rest?

Comment: I've updated the post and I've included some more info which should clear any further doubts.